# Querying SQLite database in Thunderbird

Tags: javascript, sqlite, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I want to make a small Add-on for Thunderbird that uses an SQLite database. I've created my database with "[SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/sqlite-manager/)". 
The problem is that when I access the database, I get the message that it is empty. But it isn't!

Database:

```
----------------------------
| table1 | table2 | table3 |
----------------------------
|  ...   |  ...   |  ...   |
|  ...   |  ...   |  ...   |
----------------------------
```

Here is the JavaScript code. It should return the name of tables, but I get 0.

```
  Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Sqlite.jsm");
  Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm");

  Task.spawn(function() {
    let db;
    let result;
    try {

      db = yield Sqlite.openConnection({ path: "db.sqlite" });
      result = yield db.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'");

      alert(result.length);

    } catch (ex) {
      alert("error: " + ex);
    } finally {
      if (db) yield db.close();
    }
  });
```

Can one tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Is it possible to import and then to read an already existing database in Thunderbird?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the database in the current profile's directory? If not, the db will be created there and of course be empty.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I thought it is relatively of my JavaScript file. The correct path is: extensions/db@example.de/chrome/content/db.sqlite! Is it possible to use Chrome URL as absolute path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code for Sqlite.jsm](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/modules/Sqlite.jsm#883), the path is always relative to the profile. You can however access the backstage pass of the module and copy/paste the code from openConnection. This is the object that holds the unexported symbols available in the module. Like this:

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
var {classes: Cc, interfaces: Ci, utils: Cu} = Components;

function openConnection2(path) {
  let Sqlite = Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Sqlite.jsm", {});
  let file = FileUtils.File(path);
  let identifier = Sqlite.getIdentifierByPath(path);
  let openedOptions = {};

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let dbOptions = null;
    Services.storage.openAsyncDatabase(file, dbOptions, (status, connection) => {
      if (!connection) {

        reject(new Error(`Could not open connection to ${path}: ${status}`));
        return;
      }
      log.info("Connection opened");
      try {
        resolve(
          new Sqlite.OpenedConnection(connection.QueryInterface(Ci.mozIStorageAsyncConnection),
                                      identifier, openedOptions));
      } catch (ex) {
        reject(ex);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

You can pass your own path here, this should be the full path. You can access your database by converting the chrome uri to a file uri:

```
let uri = Services.io.newURI("chrome://myext/content/db.sqlite", null, null);
let registry = Cc['@mozilla.org/chrome/chrome-registry;1']
                .getService(Ci.nsIChromeRegistry);
let path = registry.convertChromeURL(uri)
                   .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIFileURL)
                   .file.path;

yield openConnection2(path); // in your task
```

Note that you will need to specify `em:unpack` in your install.rdf to ensure that the converted uri is actually a file uri and not a jar: uri.

Comment: is there a new way to add a SQLite to Thunderbird? I read that *.jsm will no longer be supported in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

The example shown may no longer work today.
Unfortunately I not only had problems with ChromeUtils but also with https://sql.js.org/#/ a SQLite wrapper in JS / WASM, I couldn't save the database to the hard drive or into a localStorage.

Today this would more likely be done via IndexedDB.

I experimented with IndexedDB today
This works in Thunderbird!

```
function saveEmailInformation(tab, message) {
  // Open a database connection
  let openRequest = indexedDB.open("thunderbird_av",1);

  openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {
    let db = e.target.result;

    // Create an Object Store
    if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('hybridanalysis')) {
      db.createObjectStore('hybridanalysis', { keyPath: 'messageHeader' });
    }
  };

  openRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {
    let db = e.target.result;

    // Start a transaction and add data
    let transaction = db.transaction(['hybridanalysis'], 'readwrite');
    let store = transaction.objectStore('hybridanalysis');
    let item = {
      messageHeader: message.headerMessageId, // The messageId of the email
      author: message.author, // The author of the email
      subject: message.subject, // The subject of the email
      created: new Date()
    };

    // Check if the hash is defined and has a valid value
    if (typeof item.messageHeader !== 'undefined' && item.messageHeader !== '') {
      // Check if the hash already exists
      let getRequest = store.get(item.messageHeader);
      getRequest.onsuccess = function () {
        if (typeof getRequest.result === 'undefined') {
          // The hash does not exist, add the item
          let addRequest = store.add(item);
          addRequest.onsuccess = function () {
            console.log('Data added successfully');
          };
          addRequest.onerror = function () {
            console.log('Error adding data');
          };
        } else {
          console.log('The hash already exists');
        }
      };
      getRequest.onerror = function () {
        console.log('Error retrieving data');
      };
    } else {
      console.log('Invalid hash');
    }

    /*let request = store.add(item);

    request.onsuccess = function (e) {
      console.log('Data added successfully');
    };

    request.onerror = function (e) {
      console.log('Error adding data');
    };*/
  };

  openRequest.onerror = function (e) {
    console.log('Error opening the database');
  };
}
```